# myeclipse and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, myeclipse

**I have a problem, My Console output is,**

`org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL). Error: "Unsupported curveId: 29"`

Comment: The error suggests you are using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. Tagging your question with the right tags will help find the best people to answer your question.

Comment: thanks, how can i edit my question to put the rigth tag?

Comment: Hover your mouse to the right of the current tags, and the word "edit tags" appears. Or you can edit tags (as well as the title and question) if you click the "edit" link below the tags.